How would you say "He says he used to remember that." in Latin?
"He says he remembers that." would be, if I am not mistaken, "Is dicit se illius meminisse.". But how would you say "He says he used to remember that."?

Two quick points about your first translation:

It's generally not a good idea to translate an English personal pronoun in the subject position with is/ea/id. There are exceptions (e.g. when you are emphasizing the subject or constructing a relative clause), but in this case it doesn't seem necessary.
Memini takes the genitive or the accusative (along with many other constructions), but they don't necessarily mean the same thing. A rule of thumb suggested by Allen & Greenough--though I caution that this depends on the author!--is that the accusative refers to "retaining in the mind," while the genitive refers to "being mindful of something" or "mentioning something." It's also worth noting that the neuter pronoun tends to be in the accusative, not the genitive.

In short: illud (or id) meminisse is a better choice than illius meminisse. There are many examples in the corpus of the former, while most of the examples of the latter are false positives, e.g. illius nomen memini.



So, for your first sentence, I would suggest:

Dicit se illud meminisse.

For the second, the translation is a little more difficult, because the sense is that I once remembered but now do not. My suggestion would be to recast somewhat so that the meaning is, "He says that he no longer remembers." One possible way of translating this:

Dicit se iam non meminisse id.

This might not be as explicit as you need, since it could mean, "He says that he doesn't remember it now," whether or not he remembered it earlier. Another suggestion by d_e might also work:

Dicit se olim id meminisse.

(My one hesitation about this is that it recalls Virgil's famous forsan et haec olim meminisse iuvabit, where olim is construed with iuvabit with a much different meaning.)
A final option would be to translate, "He says that he forgot it," with the idea being that you can't forget something if at one point you didn't remember it:

Dicit se id oblitum esse.

